# Rotate body while adding force to it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate my Rigid-body but when I rotate it keeps moving forward and doesn't change the direction of the force being applied.

If I press button to rotate the player rotates but the force is always along the x-axis and I want the force to be at the direction of rotation. I have done this with transform.Translate but it doesn't include rigid-body. Is there anyway to fix this ? I have tried this code:

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();

}

void FixedUpdate() {
    bool activeRotation = Input.GetButton("Fire1");
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(5f * time.DeltaTime, 0f));

    if (activeRoattion == true) {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 6));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check AddRelativeForce?  I believe AddForce adds in world space, Where AddRelativeForce adds it relative to the rigidbody's coordinates.

Comment: rb.AddForce(transform.Forward * (new Vector2(5f * time.DeltaTime , 0f)));                          Need to multiply by the direction you want to go in.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard i think it would be better if he just used `rb.AddForce(transform.right * speed * 5f * time.deltaTime);`  Since that guarantees movement on the right axis of the transforms rotation.  Multiplying the forward direction with another vector does not guarantee the object will move at all.  Especially in this condition where the transform.forward is always the same since this is a 2d environment(Given away by the rigidbody2d), and the resulting movement vector will end up being (0,0,0).

Comment: Ah yeah you're right, I missed the 2D